# Cannot access method 'Handle' MediatR due to its protection level .net using xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, protected, mediatr

I want to test a handler that is protected due to the `AsyncRequestHandler` interface in `MediatR`.Here is my handler :

```
public sealed class AddUserDeviceCommandHandler : AsyncRequestHandler<AddUserDeviceCommand>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _userService;
    private readonly IRepository<UserDevice> _repository;

    public AddUserDeviceCommandHandler(ICurrentUserService userService, IRepositoryAccessor repositoryAccessor)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _repository = repositoryAccessor.GetRepository<UserDevice>(_userService.CustomerIsin,
            reThrowException: true, type: DatabaseType.Raven);
    }

    protected override async Task Handle(AddUserDeviceCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        //do do do some code
        await _repository.AddOrUpdateAsync(model);
    }
}
```

As you can see the Handle method is protected .So in my test I can't access the handle method :

```
AddUserDeviceCommand command = new AddUserDeviceCommand(data.AppBuildNo,data.Width,data.Height,data.PlatformInfo,data.DevicePlatform);
        AddUserDeviceCommandHandler handler = new AddUserDeviceCommandHandler(userservice.Object, repoacc.Object);

        handler.?????
```

appreciate for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `handler` variable as of type `IRequestHandler<AddUserDeviceCommand>`.

[`AsyncRequestHandler<TRequest>`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/49f9821547db1f86f01851baa1c1935b12029d06/src/MediatR/IRequestHandler.cs#L37) implements `IRequestHandler<TRequest>`, via which you can access its `Handle` method.

```
AddUserDeviceCommand command = new AddUserDeviceCommand(  
    ​data.AppBuildNo, data.Width, data.Height, data.PlatformInfo, data.DevicePlatform
    );
IRequestHandler<AddUserDeviceCommand> handler = new AddUserDeviceCommandHandler(
    userservice.Object, repoacc.Object
    );

await handler.Handle(command, CancellationToken.None);
```